# Using android:drawable in a ColorStateList

Tags: android, xamarin.android

When creating a `ColorStateList` for a share button, I first used  `android:drawable` to specify an `item` color like so (by accident)

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/stock_orange"/>
```

instead of `android:color` (like "normal")

```
 <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/stock_orange"/>
```

Though there wasn't a crash and a color change occurred when pressed, it was the wrong color (magenta instead of the specified orange).

**Is there an obvious explanation for this? Can/should drawables be used in a color state list?**

---

**Resource/Color/share_btn_color_state_list.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#A0A0A0"/>
  <!--QUESTION: works, but color is magenta, not orange -->
  <!--item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/stock_orange"/-->
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/stock_orange"/>
  <item android:color="@color/black"/>

</selector>
```

**Resource/Layout/share_view.xml**

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/share_btn_iv"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"/>
```

**Usage**

```
_shareButton = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.share_btn_iv);
_shareButton.Enabled = true;
_shareButton.Drawable.SetTintList(
    ColorStateList.CreateFromXml(
        Resources, 
        Resources.GetXml(Resource.Color.share_btn_color_state_list)
    )
);
```

Comment: What is the effect you want to achieve? When you `ImageView` is pressed, it has an color effect?

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Correct. The selector above works as is, though I'm wondering why the commented line works (with the drawable). If it is supported, then the drawable can point to a selector as well, which would lead to strange behavior (nested selectors).

Answer (score 1):

> drawable in a ColorStateList

One way is to customize an `ImageView` and use a combination of a `ColorFilter` and a `ColorStateList` that contains your tint color for when the button is pressed.

Extend `ImageView` and wrap `DrawableStateChanged()` with code that sets the tint based on the new state :

```
public class TintableImageView : ImageView
{
    private ColorStateList tint;

    public TintableImageView(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public TintableImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs):base(context,attrs)
    {
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public TintableImageView(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle):base(context,attrs,defStyle)
    {
        init(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void init(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        TypedArray a = context.ObtainStyledAttributes(attrs, Resource.Styleable.TintableImageView, defStyle, 0);
        tint = a.GetColorStateList(Resource.Styleable.TintableImageView_tint);
        a.Recycle();
    }

    protected override void DrawableStateChanged()
    {
        base.DrawableStateChanged();
        if(tint != null && tint.IsStateful)
        {
            UpdateTintColor();
        }
    }

    public void SetColorFilter(ColorStateList tint)
    {
        this.tint = tint;
        base.SetColorFilter(new Color(tint.GetColorForState(GetDrawableState(), new Color(0))));
    }

    private void UpdateTintColor()
    {
        var color = new Color(tint.GetColorForState(GetDrawableState(), new Color(0)));
        SetColorFilter(color);
    }
}
```

Define a custom attribute :

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="TintableImageView">
        <attr name="tint" format="reference|color" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Color selector like this : **Resource\Color\color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
  <item android:color="#00000000"/>
</selector>
```

When use this custom `ImageView` ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

 <ImageDemo.TintableImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/download"
    app:tint="@color/color_selector"
    android:clickable="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT :**

For example, add a translucent color as the color effect :

**Resource\Color\color_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="#55000000"/>
  <item android:color="#00000000"/>
</selector>
```

Effect :

[image]

Comment: Is `"@drawable/download"` that `android:src` points the above selector?

Comment: @samusarin,attribut `android:src` just display a picture as a background , the above selector is `app:tint="@color/color_selector"`.

Comment: @samusarin, I have update my answer, please check it.

Comment: In selector, can I do `<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/drawable_1"/>` ?

Comment: @samusarin, when press down, you want replace the `ImageView` with another image?

Comment: @samusarin, In my code, I have defined this selector as a `ColorStateList`, so cant do this.

Comment: I'm not looking to achieve a specific effect, just wondering if in general a drawable can be specified as an item in a ColorStateList selector (like it can in a "normal" selector"). The code in my OP works, it just displays the wrong color, which I found interesting and so made me curious.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the color state list are used to change the color of any ui element for different states  For example, a Button widget can exist in one of several different states (pressed, focused, or neither) and, using a color state list, you can provide a different color during each state.

And a StateListDrawable is a drawable object defined in XML that uses a several different images to represent the same graphic, depending on the state of the object. For example, a Button widget can exist in one of several different states (pressed, focused, or neither) and, using a state list drawable, you can provide a different background image for each state.

Though what you did worked but it is not a recommended approach

Comment: I got the impression that StateListDrawable's are generally avoided when using vector drawables ("material"), since it requires modifying the vector definition (and also has the drawback of maintaining multiple copies). The mentioned drawable above was carried over during my "port" (or refactor) from the StateListDrawable approach to the ColorStateList.